# Only get selected columns from DAX ADDCOLUMNS

Tags: sql-server, dax

Lets say that I have the two following tables:

```
Messages
MessageId | Messagedetails
12312       Something
32445       Lorem ipsum

Senders
MessageId | Sender
12312       Steve
32445       Allan
```

If I wanted a combined table on the form:

```
MessageID | Messagedetails | Sender
```

I would use the following DAX statement:

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
Messages,
"Sender", RELATED( 'Senders'[Sender] ))
```

However, what If I want the following:

```
Messagedetails | Sender
```

Or just other selected columns from the first table? What about no columns from the first table?

Answer (score 2):

If they're joined together, you can try:

```
SUMMARIZE(
   Messages,
   Messages[MessageDetails],
   Senders[Sender]
)
```

Or using what you wrote before:

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
   SUMMARIZE(
      Messages,
      Messages[MessageDetails]
   ),
   "Sender", RELATED(Senders[Sender])
)
```

Basically you use the summarize function to create the restricted table that you require and then pass this table into the ADDCOLUMNS function.  (It does not need to be summarize, any function that returns a table can be used such as VALUES())

EDIT:
I didn't see your other question.

For no columns, I generally substitute a dummy column in a summarize function

```
SUMMARIZE(
   Messages,
   "Dummy", 1
)
```